# SSRS Current Month Parameter

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters, default, monthcalendar

I have cascading date parameters year, month, date. I want SSRS to dynamically populate the current month automatically.

For year I used `="[Date].[Year].&["+CSTR(Year(Today))+"]"` and worked fine.
For Month I used `="[Date].[Month].&" & Format(Today(), "YYYYMMMM")` and IS NOT working.

My Month Parameter format is: 2016 September

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
="[Date].[Year].[Month].&["+ Cstr(Today.Year) + " " +
StrConv(MonthNAme(Today.Month),vbProperCase) +"]"
```

Also this should work

```
="[Date].[Year].[Month].&["+ StrConv(FORMAT(Today(),"yyyy MMMM"),vbProperCase) +"]"
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It didn't work. The month parameter still comes across blank. My year, month and date parameters are 3 separate parameters if that matters. I also tried modifying the above by removing the .[Year] as my MDX is [Date.Month], but still no luck.

Comment: Hi Alejandro- Thanks for your help, but still no luck with either string. Is there any other info I can provide that would help?

Comment: @Nick, where are you using the expression?

Comment: Report Parameter properties (for the month parameter)>default values>Specific values radio button>value expression.

Comment: @Nick, The expression should work, how are you testing the parameter value? What do you mean by the parameter is blank?

Comment: Testing it in visual studio preview tab. When I say the parameter is blank, I mean that nothing comes across checked. I can click the drop down and see the months. It's just that nothing is checked.

Comment: @Nick, Parameter default value is the value your parameter will take when no value is selected  in the drop down list. Add a textbox to your report and use `=Parameters!Month.Value`, preview the report and you will see the parameter default value.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try and use the CDATE function:

```
=Format(CDATE(Today()), "yyyy MMMM")
```